# install gopls/vscode without internet

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gopls

I using vscode to access via ssh a remote machine and code in there. This remote machine do not have internet connection.

How can I install gopls in this remote machine without connection internet.

Tks,

PP

Comment: You can run a proxy on your computer that the remote machine can use to access the internet: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116191/give-server-access-to-internet-via-client-connecting-by-ssh

Answer (score 0):

You could compile static binaries locally and then deploy via SSH to your remote machine, since SSH itself doesn't require an internet connection. You also have the (tedious) option of downloading all the dependencies needed for your modules, bring those over and compile them on the remote machine. Not ideal, but could be useful if you have a set of modules you want to keep with you.

Comment: SSH does not require connection in general, but if the machines are not connected on same network it wont work. This may be a point of confusion.